# How do i write a static ansi-c library using visual studio 2010

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, static-libraries

When I write and compile a lib file in VS2010 I am missing something. I somehow do not mark them correctly for export.

The console command `dumpbin.exe -headers mylib.lib > stackoverflow.txt` generates the following output. (I removed empty lines)

```
 Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 10.00.30319.01 Copyright (C)
 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
 Dump of file mylib.lib
 File Type: LIBRARY
 ANON OBJECT HEADER VALUES
                1 version
              14C machine (x86)
         515AC7B8 time date stamp Tue Apr 02 13:57:44 2013
                  ClassID: {0CB3FE38-D9A5-4DAB-AC9B-D6B6222653C2}
             171A size
                0 flags
```

I create a new empty project. The new Project is an empty static library project without pre-compiled headers. I name it mylib. Afterwards I create two files. The c file ends on .c - this marks it as an ansi-c file and the compiler will compile it as ansi-c.

mylib.h

```
#ifndef __STACKOVERFLOW_EXAMPLE_
#define __STACKOVERFLOW_EXAMPLE_

__declspec(dllexport) int test(int magic);

#endif // __STACKOVERFLOW_EXAMPLE_
```

mylib.c

```
#include "mylib.h"

int test(int magic){
    return magic * 7;
}
```

What could possibly go wrong here?
Why does my lib file contain no symbols?

---

EDIT 1:

Dropping the `__declspec(dllexport)` seems reasonalbe.

mylib.h

```
#ifndef __STACKOVERFLOW_EXAMPLE_
#define __STACKOVERFLOW_EXAMPLE_

int test(int magic);

#endif // __STACKOVERFLOW_EXAMPLE_
```

I tried this now but unfortunatelly it did not change the outcome. Still no symbols in the lib file.

---

EDIT 2:

the second part to the puzzle was my console command to reveal the symbols. The correct command is `dumpbin.exe -all mylib.lib > stackoverflow.txt`. And afterwards the public symbols are revealed.

Comment: I fear it has to do with `__declspec(dllexport)`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to omit the `__declspec(dllexport)`, this shall be used for `DLLs` only. If you compile your files just like

```
#ifndef __STACKOVERFLOW_EXAMPLE_
#define __STACKOVERFLOW_EXAMPLE_

int test(int magic);

#endif // __STACKOVERFLOW_EXAMPLE_
```

everything should be fine. See [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/85391/Microsoft-Visual-C-Static-and-Dynamic-Libraries#TheStaticLibrary) for an example.

Comment: I tried it now, still no exported symbols... this is actually my original version and the reason why i am so confused about this.

Comment: If you try `dumpbin.exe /ALL`?

Answer (score 0):

Without even knowing what kind of options you used to compile this it's hard to even try to give an answer.

But, no matter what you are trying, VS offers really poor support for the C language, some features or versions of the C language are not available at all inside VS, VS is well know to not be a really good place for C.

I suggest to switch to MinGW and stick to it.

Comment: All options are the default options for a new empty static library project. I will look into MinGW in the future.

Comment: Visual is *ok* for C89, but anything past that, and you're doomed.

Answer (score 0):

In 2013, with Visual Studio 2010, I'm getting non-empty static libraries created, but neither dumpbin nor lib produce any output whatsoever, whether I say /all, -all or /disasm, one of which should say something.

File says "current ar archive" on Windows, and on linux, 
$ ar tvf MathFuncsLib.lib
rw-rw-rw- 100666/100666  16252 Jan 13 15:29 2014 Debug/MathFuncsLib.obj

And yes, this is the trivial math library Microsoft uses for their walk-through example (:-))

Comment: hmmm,... maybe you should formulate this as a question rather than an answer.